# Any way to embedd facebook 360/180 view like in an external website?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, web, user-experience, panorama-control

I wanna make a 180 panoramic look/feel with the same control and UX as facebook embedded into my website (Based on WordPress).

Example of my picture:
https://www.facebook.com/FinestraSuites/photos/a.1640510502635175.1073741830.788414251178142/1738959052790319/?type=3&theater

Is there any recommended plugin or another way to make/transfer it to my website?

- I tried few WordPress Plugins or Javascript scripts without much success, the UX is very different and hasn't given me the result I wanted.

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Comment: https://pannellum.org/ just google javascript 360 photo library.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I will try the pannellum.org, he seems nice but still doesn't have the Facebook UX / tilt experience.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "RSV 360 View" Plugin and use shortcode [rsv360_view image="abc.jpg" width="900" height="300" stitched="4320" responsive="true"]

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't do the job. No photo tilt gesture and the animation is a bit pixelated. thanks for your answer and help, any idie on another plugin / framework / sulotion to enable the photo tilt gesture like facebook do? (same UX).

Comment: try WP-VR-view plugin with [vrview img=”URL for photosphere image”] shortcode